# Which Stored Procedure access my Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have the following strange problem that i can't solve till now:
We have a portal database that contain `user` table which contain a boolean column called `IsAvtive` tat determined if the user is active ( can make login to our portal ) or not ..
this column value is changed to be `False` by unknown code .. I search a lot about the source code that change it but i can't find ( we have a lot of old DLL and code that i can't see all) ,we always use stored procedure to update this table ..
I think If is there any way to know the stored procedure that access this table during last 7 days and then I cam trace them ?

Comment: How frequently does this happen? Any specific time / interval? Do you have any idea at all as to around when it happens?

Answer (score 1):

Some options

- Add a trigger to the table that logs into another table
- Run SQL Profiler
- Remove write permissions on this column, see who calls

Answer (score 0):

You probably could check into Logs.
Take a look into C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA and the database name _log.ldf

Comment: hope it helps : http://www.databasedesign-resource.com/sql-server-transaction-log.html